# Declaring a predicate dynamic in gprolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-directive-dynamic

I have this code in Prolog:

```
dynamic(player_at/1).
player_at(house).
goto(X) :- retract(player_at(house)), assert(player_at(X)).
```

But I still get this error:

```
uncaught exception: error(permission_error(modify,static_procedure,player_at/1),retract/1)
```

when I execute goto(foo).

I've read the [dynamic documentation](http://contraintes.inria.fr/~haemmerl/gprolog-rh/doc/manual021.html#htoc47), but I can't figure out how to use it, at least in gprolog. Am I missing something?

Comment: Eventually you should get already an exception during the consult of your program. It should not allow a dynamic(_) fact. The ISO standard only says that dynamic is a directive, but in most Prologs it is also a built-in, and can thus not be asserted as a fact.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fix the first line by prepending `:-`:

```
:- dynamic(player_at/1).
```

Without `:-` the line would dreefine predicate `dynamic/1`, instead of executing the existing `dynamic` predicate.

Other prolog implementations (but not gprolog) support this as well:

```
:- dynamic player_at/1.
```

Comment: I tried that - I get syntax error: . or operator expected after expression. It doesn't like the dynamic without a parenthesis.